# eclipse content assist not showing methods

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

after installing some plugins for my eclipse, I noticed that my content assist is not working correctly. It doesn't show the available methods

I already tried resetting the default settings of content assist but it doesn't work.

*tried it inside the main method but it doesn't work either
*tried it using eclipse juno, it works but i want to use kepler
[image]

Comment: Did you reset the Advanced preferences as well? Does the project target a valid JRE?

Comment: update ur screen shot with `main` method problem.